# Export private keys from a wallet.dat file using BTCrecover

Tags: wallet-recovery, bitcoin-qt-setup, private-key-export

Is there a way to export private keys from a wallet.dat file using BTCrecover? I've been unsuccessful in achieving this using Bitcoin-qt or pywallet with an older wallet.dat file from 2018.

Answer (score 1):

If the wallet was protected by a password, the keys will be encrypted. You can only obtain the keys using tools like BTCRecover if you know almost all of the password, or maybe if you know the password is very short. You might have to run BTCRecover for weeks, months or years. Maybe longer.